# Table Values() Constructor for Updating Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I just moved an app from a local instance where I used Postgres to a Google Compute Engine virtual instance where I'm using Google Cloud SQL, built on MySQL.

Ever since the move, this SQL query is no longer working:

```
"UPDATE events e SET e.photographers = up.photographers FROM (VALUES "+ value_pairs +") AS up(id, photographers) WHERE up.id = e.id"
```

where `value_pairs` = (1,2)

Here's the exact error I'm seeing:

`error running query { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (VALUES (1,2)) AS up(id, photographers) WHERE up.id = e.id' at line 1]`

The output seems correct ... anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Update / Solution**
Should have clarified, value_pairs can grow to be multiple values, i.e. ((4,2), (6,1), (10,3), ...)

Due to the relatively simple nature of this query, I ended up going with an `INSERT` query using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause:

```
("INSERT INTO events (id,photographers) VALUES "+ value_pairs + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE photographers=VALUES(photographers)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace `(VALUES "+ value_pairs +") AS up(id, photographers)` with something like this:

```
mysql> (SELECT 1 AS photographers, 2 AS id) UNION (SELECT 3, 4) UNION (SELECT 5, 6);
+---------------+----+
| photographers | id |
+---------------+----+
|             1 |  2 | 
|             3 |  4 | 
|             5 |  6 | 
+---------------+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple update:

```
UPDATE events 
SET photographers = 2
WHERE id = 1;
```

MySql doesn't support the non-standard syntax of PostgreSql.

---

If multiple values are needed, a multitable update syntax might be used:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

One option is to insert values to a temporary table - as @Denis wrote - then perform an update:

```
UPDATE table t, temporary_table tmp
SET t.photographers = tmp.photographers
WHERE t.id = tmp.id
```

Another option is - as @Razvan Musaloiu-E. wrote - build a dynamic query with union:

```
UPDATE table t, (
   SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS photographers
   UNION
   SELECT 5, 7
   UNION
   SELECT 15, 67
   UNION
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
   UNION
   SELECT 234, 567 
) AS tmp
SET t.photographers = tmp.photographers
WHERE t.id = tmp.id
```

Comment: Thank you, but for my use case that won't suffice - post updated to clarify; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table to run your query in MySQL:

```
create temporary table src ...
insert into src values ...
```

And then run your update using `src`. It's not as pretty as the anonymous temporary table that you're currently using, but it'll work.

Another approach is to use a giant case statement:

```
update events
set photographers = case id
                    when 1 then 2
                    ...
                    end
where id in (1, ...)
```

Comment: thank you -- while searching for `UPDATE FROM` guidance, I've run across a few things saying that `MERGE INTO` might work nicely, but I've never used the command.

Comment: Best I'm aware, that's Oracle rather than MySQL. The latter offers upserts using `replace into`, whose syntax is a bit like an insert and which should indeed get the job done too.