# How to build a large column of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What's the best way to dynamically build a column of values?

My PHP app will have the ID fields of a large number of records (<=30k). I need to update these records and I'm wondering if I'm overlooking an easy to do this. What I've considered so far is:

(1) Use a derived table built using UNION ALL.

```
UPDATE t1
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT 1 id UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 id UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 id UNION ALL
              SELECT 4 ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   SET t1.status = 'A'
```

In testing, I've exhausted my memory limit by too many UNION ALLs.

(2) Use a temporary table. The INSERT statement can be built by imploding my array of ID fields.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id INT)

INSERT INTO temp (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)

UPDATE t1
 INNER JOIN temp ON t1.id = temp.id
   SET t1.status = 'A'
```

Is there some other way? Thanks!

Comment: Will the IDs be sequential as in your example code, or more random?

Comment: The IDs won't likely be sequential. The PHP app will basically grab all the data, process each row, and then conditionally update the status. I'll be tracking those requiring update in a simple array and then issuing the UPDATE afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much it if you are using MySQL.

Some engines support the VALUES clause as a table value constructor(like SQL Server), so you could skip the temporary table step.

```
select * from (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) q(i);
```

Similar question here: [Table Values() Constructor for Updating Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873439/table-values-constructor-for-updating-multiple-rows)

Looks like you are stuck with a temp table or UNION if you have to UPDATE.

If you can try this (but it will create rows that aren't there)...

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, status) VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (3, 'A') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=VALUES(status)
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd866)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm committed to using MySQL here. I do like the DUPLICATE KEY suggestion, that's pretty clever!